# Delete Directories with files under 5MB

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I would like to delete all directories under a starting directory that do not contain any files larger than 5MB.

My first thought was to delete all files less than 5MB in one command, then delete all empty directories, but that will not work. If a directory contains a file greater than 5MB, I want to keep all files within the directory and not delete the directory.

Ideally, the folders directly under the starting point would never be deleted even if they are empty (John and Michael in the example below).

Given `c:\Media` as the starting point:

```
c:\Media\
   John\  --this directory should not be deleted because Dir 3 remains
      Directory 1\  --this directory and all its files should be deleted
         small-file.1.txt [2kb]
         small-file.2.txt [7kb]
      Directory 2\  --this directory and everything below should be deleted
         Subdirectory 1\
            small-file-3.txt [1kb]
      Directory 3\ --this directory should NOT be deleted
         large-file-1.txt [6mb]  -- should not be deleted
         small-file-4.txt [8kb]  -- should not be deleted
   Michael\
      Directory 4\  -- should be deleted
         small-file-5.txt [12kb]  
         small-file-2.txt [12kb]
```

After the PowerShell script runs, I would like the directory structure to look like:

```
c:\Media\
   John\
      Directory 3\
         large-file-1.txt [6mb]  -- should not be deleted
         small-file-4.txt [8kb]  -- should not be deleted
   Michael\
```

If the `Michael` folder ends up deleted, that wouldn't be the end of the world.

Comment: This is a great list of requirements that shows what you are trying to accomplish, but demonstrates no attempt to do it yourself

Comment: I didn't feel like my sloppy attempts were worth documenting, but here is where I got before I realized the wrong direction I was taking, as noted in my question:  PS C:\temp\deleteplay> ls -Path C:\temp\deleteplay -recurse | where {$_.Length -lt 5mb -and !$_.PSIsContainer} | Remove-Item -WhatIf

Answer (score 2):

I think that Cole9350 has the right idea about finding files over 5mb and excluding those folders from being deleted. Plus that gives you the ability to save root folders. I do not trust the file system `-Exclude` capabilities, so I would suggest moving that to a Where clause. Also, to check if a folder contains a folder down the line that has a 5MB file, well, the only way I could figure out was to run a directory listing on each folder and check if it has any of the whitelisted folders within it, so that's what I did in my script.

So this should exclude the John and Michael folders, and any folders with a 5MB file in it, or that contains a folder that has a 5MB folder somewhere down the chain. A little slow, since it has a lot of recursion, but thorough, and should be safe.

```
#Find folders with files > 5MB
$Exclude = gci C:\Media -recurse | ?{$_.Length -gt 5mb} | Select -ExpandProperty PSParentPath -Unique

$folders = gci C:\Media -Directory -Recurse|%{if((gci $_ -Directory -Recurse)){if(!(compare-object (gci $_ -Directory -Recurse|select -ExpandProperty pspath) $Exclude -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual)){$_}}}|select -ExpandProperty FullName

#Add root folders
$ExcludeRoot += GCI C:\Media -Directory | Select -Expand FullName

$folders | ?{$ExcludeRoot -notcontains $_.FullName} | Remove-Item $_ -Recurse -WhatIf
```

Now, you only asked about directories, not files. So if You have:

C:\Media\John\Subfolder1\SubfolderA\ET.mp4 <1,254,132,001 bytes>

You want to keep SubfolderA, but do you want to keep the files in Subfolder1 as well? My script will keep the files in both of them, since it is only deleting folders and not specifically files.

Comment: Yes, I want to keep all files if there is a 5MB file keeping a folder whitelisted.

Comment: OK, that should do what you want then. Let me know if you have any issues

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, it seems it would be easier to try to find the files greater than 5mb, and only keep those folders:

```
#declare array
$arr = @()
#Find all Files greater than 5 mb, add the parent folder to the array
ls -Recurse | ? {$_.length -gt 5mb -and !$_.PSIsContainer} | % { $arr += $_.PSParentPath }
#Remove the folders, excluding the ones with files > 5mb
ls -recurse -Exclude $arr | Remove-item -recurse -WhatIf
```

Comment: Looks like it mostly works except in the case of 'John\Directory 2\Subdirectory 1'. It adds 'Subdirectory 1' to the exclude list. The ls command finds the 'Directory 2' and tries to delete it.

Comment: For that piece, I would just clean up empty folders after : `ls -recurse | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0)} | Remove-item -recurse -whatif`